# How to make a signal like onEditingFinished available to individual TextInput elements reusing one common TextInput defined

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I am new to `QML` & `Qt`. I am trying to make multiple `TextInput` elements which can send their own `text` when `onEditingFinished` is triggered. Following is a `TextInput` item that I have created in `MyTextField.qml`:

**MyTextField.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Item {

implicitHeight: 200
implicitWidth: 1000

property alias inputMethodHints: myTextField.inputMethodHints
property alias text: myTextField.text

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent
    radius: 40
  }


TextInput {
    id: myTextField
    objectName: "myTextField"
    anchors.fill: parent
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    font.pixelSize: 300
    color: 'white'

    signal qmlSignal(string msg)
    onEditingFinished: qmlSignal(text)  //This works
  }
}
```

I am trying to use the above `TextInput` element in another `qml` file like below:

**SomeOtherPage.qml**

```
Column {
    anchors.top: parent.top
    anchors.left: parent.left
    anchors.right: parent.right
    anchors.margins: theme.defaultMargin

    MyTextField {
        id: textfield1
        objectName: "textfield1"
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        text: qsTr("some text")

       signal qmlSignal11(string msg)
       onEditingFinished: qmlSignal11(text)  //This doesn't work !!
    }

    MyTextField {
        id: textfield2
        objectName: "textfield2"
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.right: parent.right
        text: qsTr("some other text")

       signal qmlSignal22(string msg)
       onEditingFinished: qmlSignal22(text)  //This doesn't work !!
    }
}
```

In`MyTextField` blocks, QML doesn't allow me to use `onEditingFinished` at all. It complains `Cannot assign to non-existent property "onEditingFinished"` when I run the app.

*If I handle `onEditingFinished` from the parent `TextInput` I created, it works fine & sends the signal to my `C++` class. But I am trying to use `onEditingFinished` in `textfield1` & `textfield2`. Qml reports that `onEditingFinished` property is not available.* **How I can make `onEditingFinished` available in `textfield1` & `textfield2` so that I send the text of each unique textfield I create.**

Comment: The error is pretty clear - your item doesn't have `onEditingFinished` signal. And that's absolutely right,there is no such signal in `MyTextField`. So you have to add the signal in root of `MyTextField` and emit if from `TextInput.onEditingFinished`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only the root element, its properties, signals, and methods, are visible from the outside of MyTextField.qml. Just like you already alias a few properties of the inner myTextField, you must also forward the signals you want to use from the outside:

**MyTextField.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Item {
    id: root
    ...
    signal editingFinished() // <==
    ...
    TextField {
        id: myTextField
        ...
        onEditingFinished: root.editingFinished() // <==
    }
}
```